# Unable to understand notation regarding Shannon's theorem

Tags: encryption

the following equation is used to prove the Shannon's theorem by showing the existence of two messages $m_0, m_1$ if $|K| < |M|$ but I'm unable to visualize/understand the probabilities. **Especially the $Pr$ over $K$ thing** doesn't get into my head. Anyone able to explain it?

- $\mathcal{K}$ is the keyspace
- $\text{Pr}$ means probability
- $m_0$ and $m_1$ are messages from the message space $M$
- $c$ is the ciphertext
- $K$ is a random variable determining the key
- $\text{Enc}(k, m)$ is the encryption algorithm

Then:
$\underset{\mathcal{K}}{\text{Pr}}[\text{Enc}(K, m_0) = c] \neq \underset{\mathcal{K}}{\text{Pr}}[\text{Enc}(K, m_1) = c]$

Comment: Welcome to CryptoSE. I might paraphrase this as “The number of keys that would encrypt $m_0$ as $c$ is not the same as the number of keys that would encrypt $m_1$ as $c$”. This is not quite fully precise, but close.

Comment: A definition of (discrete) probability may help. $\underset{\mathcal K}\Pr[K\text{ smurfs}]$ is defined as the ratio of: the number of elements $K$ in set $\mathcal K$ such that $K\text{ smurfs}$, over the number of elements in set $\mathcal K$. This ratio is thus a rational in range $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\underset{\mathcal{K}}{\text{Pr}}[\text{Enc}(K, m_0) = c]$ (and similarly $\underset{\mathcal{K}}{\text{Pr}}[\text{Enc}(K, m_1) = c]$) means the probability that $\text{Enc}(k, m_0) = c$, where you choose the key $k\in \mathcal{K}$ at random. Notice that, here, the values $m_0$ and $c$ are *fixed*, so what we want to know is, for these fixed $m_0$ and $c$, what is the probability that a uniformly random key $k$ results in encrypting $m_0$ to $c$.

As @fgrieu pointed out in the comments, the probability of a discrete event is simply the number of "favorable" cases divided by the total number of cases, so here it would be

$$\underset{\mathcal{K}}{\text{Pr}}[\text{Enc}(K, m_0) = c] = \frac{|\{k\in\mathcal{K} : \text{Enc}(k, m_0) = c\}|}{|\mathcal{K}|}.$$

---

**PS:** Sometimes we also add the *randomness of the encryption algorithm* into the equation. This is not that relevant for this discussion, but what this means is that you consider an encryption algorithm of the form $\text{Enc}(k, m, r)$, where $r\in\{0,1\}^\ell$ (for some $\ell$) is chosen uniformly random. Then you simply add $r$ as a subscript in the probability.